# Issue on Event registration with Wordpress-CiviCRM, message "You do not have permission to access this page."

Tags: wordpress, civievent, permissions, registration

We had to reinstall wordpress after a Malware infection.
We have now the version WordPress 5.5.3.
We are now facing an issue with the registration for an event. In CiviCRM, It is working well if we register one person to an event.
But when we try to do it in Wordpress, we have the following message : "You do not have permission to access this page."
On the WordPress Access Control, the anonymous user is able to "register for events". But in wordpress, using the form, impossible to register.
Do you have any idea ???

Comment: what is your Civi version?

Comment: Dear @PradeepNayak, the version of CiviCRM is 5.22.0

Comment: Not an answer as such, but you need to have CiviCRM 5.26+ for it to work properly on WordPress 5.5+. Can you upgrade and see if your problem persists? See https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice